# callback function for an ajax form in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, search

i make a wordpress advance search with jquery.
when user click on search button, by using jquery i get all my search parameters and send with $.post() function to admin-ajax.php ...
i create a function in functions.php file and receive all search values and write wp_query to fetch wp posts.

```
$args = array(
'category_name' => '3d');$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'. the_permalink() .'">test</a>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

in the above code when i printed a tag, output is something like this:

```
http://localhost/site/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%81%db%8c%d9%84%d9%85-zootopia/test0
```

problem 1: test is a link but doesn't have any href! the href of link printed outside of link like a string!
problem 2: "0" character automatically printed after all output values even empty echo in php will print "0" character!
please help me, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace code with this. Because you are using `the_permalink()` instead of `get_the_permalink()` when inside **echo**.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/

```
$args = array('category_name' => '3d');
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">test</a>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: thanks very much... but what is "0" character? this appear in all responses from server to jquery

Comment: You need to add die() method end of function like this: function yourFunction(){
 //Write code here...
die();
};

Comment: help me to replace $post->ID() with correct query? like this: get_post_meta($post->ID, 'movie250',true)

Comment: Where you are using $post->ID().

Comment: You can send post id using ajax like: <input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="<?php the_ID() ?>"> and php code like this: get_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'movie250',true)